# How to make a correct if-statement to filter out values from a xml-file

Tags: php, if-statement

## Edit 3:

As requested, I'm trying to simplify my question.

Here is a sample of some of my data from a xml file:

```
<entry>
    <title>Entry 1</title>
    <f:max_value_a>499 999</f:max_value_a>
    <f:max_value_b>999 999</f:max_value_b>
    <f:min_value_a>0</f:min_value_a>
    <f:min_value_b>500 000</f:min_value_b>
    <f:min_value_c>1 000 000</f:min_value_c>
    <f:value_for_a>5,10</f:value_for_a>
    <f:value_for_b>4,50</f:value_for_b>
    <f:value_for_c>3,90</f:value_for_c>
</entry>    


<entry>
    <title>Entry 2</title>
    <f:min_value_a>0</f:min_value_a>
    <f:value_for_a>4,20</f:value_for_a>
</entry>

<entry>
    <title>Entry 3</title>
    <f:max_value_a>1 999 999</f:max_value_a>
    <f:min_value_a>100 000</f:min_value_a>
    <f:min_value_b>2 000 000</f:min_value_b>
    <f:value_for_a>3,735</f:value_for_a>
    <f:value_for_b>3,445</f:value_for_b>
</entry>
```

f:value_for_d is the highest value, and f:value_for_c is lower than d, and so on.

I have a dynamic targetvalue (lets just go with 2 000 000 in this example)

I want to get the value where max_value is greater than the targetvalue, but sometimes max_value is not defined and then set to "0". "0"  in max_value should mean unlimited "roof". The min_value can not be greater than targetvalue, but sometimes min_value is not defined and then set to "0". "0" min_value should mean a unlimited "floor".

I have tried with this code

```
if ($value_for_d > 0 ){
    if (($min_value_d <= $targetvalue) xor ($min_value_d == 0)){
        if (($max_value_d >= $targetvalue) xor ($max_value_d == 0)){
            $query_result = TRUE;
            $value = $value_for_d;
        }
    }
}elseif ($value_for_c > 0 ){
    if (($min_value_c <= $targetvalue) xor ($min_value_c == 0)){
        if (($max_value_c >= $targetvalue) xor ($max_value_c == 0)){
            $query_result = TRUE;
            $value = $value_for_c;
        }
    }
}elseif ($value_for_b > 0 ){
    if (($min_value_b <= $targetvalue) xor ($min_value_b == 0)){
        if (($max_value_b >= $targetvalue) xor ($max_value_b == 0)){
            $query_result = TRUE;
            $value = $value_for_b;
        }
    }
}elseif ($value_for_a > 0 ){
    if (($min_value_a <= $targetvalue) xor ($min_value_a == 0)){
        if (($max_value_a >= $targetvalue) xor ($max_value_a == 0)){
            $query_result = TRUE;
            $value = $value_for_a;
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this code with a targetvalue of "2 000 000", I get this result:

```
Entry 1 - 3.9 (correct value is 3.9)
Entry 2 - 0 (correct value is 4.2)
Entry 3 - 3.445 (correct value is 3.445)
```

If I set the targetvalue to even lower, to 500 000, I get 0 on all my entries.

## Edit 4:

If I do:

```
var_dump($min_value_d,$max_value_d,$min_value_c,$max_value_c,$min_value_b,$max_‌​value_b,$min_value_a,$max_value_a);
```

I get this output: https://dpaste.de/DtjhO/

Comment: Have you tried XPath Query? http://www.php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: Could you explain what xpath could help me with? My problem is the if-statement, not getting the entires from the xml file.

Comment: Your if statement compares to $max_value_x. Where do you get the value for this? You can wrap with: isset($entry->max_value_x) to avoid asking for elements not existing. But only in SimpleXml objects.

Comment: Updated question with the code I use to get the value from xml, but I did not think that would be relevant to the question.

Comment: You need to define "make it work" a little better. How is it suppose to work when the data you need for the if doesn't exist? I think your problem is not with the existing, you have to work out all the possible scenarios of what you describe as "different setup".

Comment: Okay. Updated my question. Let me know if I need to explain further.

Comment: @Garreth00 What value does a minimum get if it is not specified? What about a maximum?

Comment: @meiamsome: If not a minimum is specified, the value of minimum is 0. The same for maximum. If not specified, the value of maximum is 0.

Comment: @Garreth00 So it is possible for one to have a minimum of 500,000 but a maximum of 0?

Comment: @Garreth00 what you want to do when maxvalue is lower than target but not 0 ? just ignore and move to the next maxvalue ? the guidelines you need to follow are poorly explained and will be a lot confused with all those Edits giving not sense to it, you should edit your question and first explain what guidelines you need to follow, then show what you are trying to do, a sample of the data you're using and what is not working or is expected from it.

Comment: @meiamsome: Yes, it is possible to have a minimum of 500 000, and 0 as maxvalue. If maxvalue is lower than the target, it should be ignored, because then target is greater/higher than maxvalue.

Comment: @Garreth00 What I'm trying to say is, there's no point defining a region with a maximum below the minimum you'd never actually be able to access it so you might as well not define it.

Comment: `if (((is_null($max_value_*) && $targetvalue == 0) || $max_value_* >= $targetvalue) && ((is_null($min_value_*) && $targetvalue == 0) || $min_value_* <= $targetvalue)))`

How about this ? if the max is null or empty compare target to 0 otherwise compare maxvalue to target same goes to min ?

Comment: My question is yet again updated, to make it easier to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the regions are always exclusive and always in the right order, I'd suggest you do something like this:

```
<?php
if($min_value_d <= $targetvalue) {
    $value = $value_for_d;
} else if($min_value_c <= $targetvalue) {
    $value = $value_for_c;
} else if($min_value_b <= $targetvalue) {
    $value = $value_for_b;
} else if($min_value_b <= $targetvalue) {
    $value = $value_for_b;
}
?>
```

However, if they are not always exclusive, you should be returning some form of array, as it may fulfil multiple criteria:
Assuming that $min_value_x is not set when it is not in the XML (As in, no minimum) and $max_value_x is not set when it is not in the XML (As in, no maximum)

```
<?php
$values = array();
//if (there is no minimum or its smaller than target)                                         and (there is no maximum or its larger than target)                                           and at least one of them is non-null
if((is_null($min_value_d) || preg_replace('/([^0-9.])/i', '',$min_value_d) <= $targetvalue) && (is_null($max_value_d) || preg_replace('/([^0-9.])/i', '',$max_value_d) >= $targetvalue) && !(is_null($min_value_d) && is_null($max_value_d))) $values[] = $value_for_d;
if((is_null($min_value_c) || preg_replace('/([^0-9.])/i', '',$min_value_c) <= $targetvalue) && (is_null($max_value_c) || preg_replace('/([^0-9.])/i', '',$max_value_c) >= $targetvalue) && !(is_null($min_value_c) && is_null($max_value_c))) $values[] = $value_for_c;
if((is_null($min_value_b) || preg_replace('/([^0-9.])/i', '',$min_value_b) <= $targetvalue) && (is_null($max_value_b) || preg_replace('/([^0-9.])/i', '',$max_value_b) >= $targetvalue) && !(is_null($min_value_b) && is_null($max_value_b))) $values[] = $value_for_b;
if((is_null($min_value_a) || preg_replace('/([^0-9.])/i', '',$min_value_a) <= $targetvalue) && (is_null($max_value_a) || preg_replace('/([^0-9.])/i', '',$max_value_a) >= $targetvalue) && !(is_null($min_value_a) && is_null($max_value_a))) $values[] = $value_for_a; 

?>
```

As it turns out, your items are formatted with spaces, thus when converted to a float for interpretation it only looked at the first set of numbers. `preg_replace('/([^0-9.])/i', '', $var)` removes anything non-numerical. (This is quite computationally expensive, mind)

Comment: This is purely about the best way to find which regions its in, if that doesn't work, I'd suggest you echo your $mins and $maxes to check you're getting the right thing from your XML. You might also want to check you're casting your values to numbers and not comparing on the strings!

Comment: I have tried with your first example, but that did not work.

Also tried your last example, but I only get empty array's, maybe I did not use it correctly?

Comment: @Garreth00 could you run this: `var_dump($min_value_d,$max_value_d,$min_value_c,$max_value_c,$min_value_b,$max_value_b,$min_value_a,$max_value_a);` and provide the output?

Comment: The output is too long for stackoverflow, but here is a paste: https://dpaste.de/DtjhO/

Comment: I tried your code, but when I do `var_dump($values);` I get `array(0) {
}` on every entry.

Comment: @Garreth00 I had a lot of wrong !s, I'm pretty sure it should work now.

Comment: Hmm, still getting only empty array.

Comment: @Garreth00 Okay, my bad. It actually works now (I tried it too: http://meiamso.me/test.php )

Comment: Tried your code, and now I get some output at least, but it is still giving me the wrong values. Here is the output with 400 000 as a targetvalue: https://dpaste.de/Em93u/

Comment: @Garreth00 Looks to me like you're plugging the minimums from the file into the maximums of the code and vice versa? That wouldn't work for the second one, unless you're handling the zero as intending no limit and setting it to null?

Comment: @Garreth00 Okay, used your code, found the problem and fixed it. Updated reply. (Oh and the [] is meant to be there on the values assignment if you wish to get all the categories it fits (Which I doubt you are))